# Using Emojione with tinymce

Tags: javascript, editor, tinymce-4, emojione

I want to integrate EmojiOne emojis in TinyMCE editor as a TinyMCE plugin.
EmojiOne has javascript plugin called EmojiOne-Area. But I am not sure about how it could be used in TinyMCE editor.

Any idea about how the plugin could be integrated with TinyMCE?
(Replace default TinyMCE emoticons plugin with EmojiOne-Area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create your own plugin for this.  You can look at how the standard `emoticons` plugin is built and adjust that as needed to do what you need with that 3rd party product.

Comment: Can't `EmojiOne-Area` directly be used with TinyMCE?

Comment: If they built a plugin themselves sure ... if not how would you "use" those emojis in TinyMCE?